# How to configure logging for Kafka producers?

Tags: java, logging, apache-kafka, log4j, kafka-producer-api

I am using Kafka producer client and i don't have any log4j configuration in my project.

On running, the program prints a lot of Kafka Debug logs  which i really don't want.

So, i tried to add a log4j.properties to set log level to ERROR as below which does not seem to work:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR
```

How do i change Kafka Log Level?

Answer (score 16):

Use the command line flag `-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/path/to/log4j.properties` when running your client.

Example log4j property files:

- https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/config/tools-log4j.properties

  - Used by tools like mirror maker, really just stdout
- https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/config/log4j.properties

  - Used by tools like kafka server

For mirror maker and other tools that result in a call to `kafka-run-class.sh`, you can use the env variable `KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS` (set to something like `-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/path/to/log4j.properties`) to change the logging configuration.  See: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.10.2/bin/kafka-run-class.sh#L158

Example of my `log4j.properties` file for mirror maker that I use for testing.

```
# https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/config/tools-log4j.properties

log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stderr

log4j.appender.stderr=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stderr.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stderr.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n
log4j.appender.stderr.Target=System.err
```

Answer (score 4):

Try adding logging.level.org.apache.kafka: DEBUG into your clients configuration properties. 
I am using Springboot and this is the format. Use appropriate format for your clients program.

Comment: `Cannot set level: WARNING for 'org.apache.kafka'` any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I assumed you were talking about Kafka server logs. You can change log level to ERROR using following config

```
log4j.logger.kafka=ERROR, kafkaAppender
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am talking bout the logs that come up in my client program..not the kafka server as such...

Answer (score 1):

```
org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.WARN);
org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.WARN);
org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("kafka").setLevel(Level.WARN);
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring allows us to configure the package-level logging as follows.

Steps

- Identify your logs - (I don't need to get `info` logs of confluent kafka packages.)
- Find out the package first - `io.confluent.kafka`
- Set it in the application properties

```
logging.level.io.confluent.kafka=WARN
```

In your case, you need to set the below in your application properties. I added confluent kafka as well, if you use it.

```
logging.level.org.apache.kafka=WARN
logging.level.io.confluent.kafka=WARN
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the logging level as below in `application.yml` file or your properties file.

```
logging:
  level:
    root: INFO
    org:
      apache:
        kafka: WARN
```

By defining the above, Kafka will print out only the warnings logs.